# How to derive an association from a SemanticImport of a website's data?

Tags: import

How might I make an association out of web-derived data imported with SemanticImport?

```
knownRatios = Association[Flatten[StringCases[Flatten[SemanticImport[ "http://www.huygens-fokker.org/docs/intervals.html",Automatic,"Rows",ExcludedLines->{Append[Range[10],Range[519,539]]}, HeaderLines->0]],StartOfLine|WordBoundary~~a:NumberString~~ "/"~~b:NumberString~~Whitespace|WordBoundary~~c:___~~EndOfLine|"\n" ->  a~~"/"~~b~~" "~~"->"~~" "~~"\""~~c~~"\""]]]
```

I have also attempted these, to no avail:

```
Association @@ knownRatios

Association @@@ knownRatios
```

I appreciate your help, and thank you all in advance...

F.

Comment: The problem is that each element is a string, not a rule. Take a look at the `InputForm`. `"1/1 -> \"unison, perfect prime\""`

Comment: Awesome and thank you for responding!  I added an 'InputForm before the Association[], and IT WORKED!!!

Comment: Make this an answer, and the prize is yours, my friend!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the comment.

```
ToExpression /@ 
  Flatten@StringCases[
    Flatten[SemanticImport[
      "http://www.huygens-fokker.org/docs/intervals.html", Automatic, 
      "Rows", ExcludedLines -> {Append[Range[10], Range[519, 539]]}, 
      HeaderLines -> 0]], 
    StartOfLine | WordBoundary ~~ a : NumberString ~~ "/" ~~ 
      b : NumberString ~~ Whitespace | WordBoundary ~~ c : ___ ~~ 
      EndOfLine | "\n" -> 
     a ~~ "/" ~~ b ~~ " " ~~ "->" ~~ " " ~~ "\"" ~~ c ~~ 
      "\""] // Association
```

> <|1 -> "unison, perfect prime", 2 -> "octave", 3/2 -> "perfect fifth",
>   ... |>

Comment: Your answer not only works, it is aesthetically pleasing to the eye and is highly readable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This might give you what you want.

```
ClearAll[ratioFile,knownRatios]
ratioFile=SemanticImport["http://www.huygens-fokker.org/docs/intervals.html"];
knownRatios=Association[Flatten[StringCases[#, a:NumberString ~~ "/" ~~ b:NumberString ~~ 
  Whitespace | WordBoundary ~~ c:___ ~~ EndOfString -> {a ~~ "/" ~~ b -> c}]& /@ Select[Flatten[Values[Normal[ratioFile]]], StringLength[#] > 1 && ContainsAny[{StringTake[#, 1]}, ToString[#] & /@ Range[9]] &]]];
```

There are probably ways of combining my select statement with the pattern (taken mostly from yours).

Comment: My friend, I thank you for your help!